# Sencha List does not appear when trying to add() it to pabel

Tags: sencha-touch

This is really wired. I have a tab in a TabPanel that I want to refresh every time the user taps it. In the tab there should be a list of things. when i am trying to add the list to the panel(the tab container), it is just do not appear! when i try to add other things they aper normally!

For example:

```
var listConfiguration = this.getListConfiguration();
var myPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
     html: 'This will be added to a Container'
});

Ext.getCmp('Peoplebutton').add(listConfiguration);
Ext.getCmp('Peoplebutton').add(myPanel);
```

This code gets the html perfectly in the place! but the list is not shown! The list code is working fine, I have checked it several times...
I would be very happy if someone can help me (:

The list code, working fine for sure

```
 getListConfiguration: function() {
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: ['firstName', 'lastName'],
        sorters: 'firstName',
        autoLoad: true,
         grouper: {
            groupFn: function(record) {
                return record.get('firstName')[0];
           }
        },

        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'contacts.json'
        }
    });
    return {
        xtype: 'list',
        id: 'list',
        itemTpl: '{firstName} ,{lastName}',
        grouped: true,
        indexBar: true,
        infinite: true,
        useSimpleItems: true,
        variableHeights: true,
        striped: true,
        ui: 'round',
        store: store
    };
}
```

Comment: So is the tab containing the list getting generated, but the list itself just doesn't appear?

Comment: yes. solved by next answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be an issue with the height of the list component.

Try adding a fixed height to the list, or maybe flex: 1.

Hope it helps-